# randomly selecting rows with header intact

Tags: bash, shell

How can I select 500 rows randomly from a text file, but make sure that the header is always included. My file looks like

Col1 Col2

A     B

C     D

etc. And the first line is the header. I tried sort -r filename|head -n 500 but that does not ensure that the header is always included. Thanks

Comment: There's not enough of a sample to see how the header and data might differ.  But sorting the file does not make it random, in any case.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: I guess OP meant to use the `-R` (sort randomly) option of GNU `sort`, rather than `-r` (reverse)?

Comment: Could be Linux (for bash, I could assume either OSX or Linux).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say

```
{ IFS= read -r head; echo "$head"; shuf | head -n 500; } < file
```

---

Upon further reflection, that may not be the best solution: it shuffles the file, so the randomly selected lines are out of order. This may not matter

If it does matter, here's a technique:

```
sed -n "$({ echo 1; seq $(wc -l <file) | sed 1d | shuf | head -n 500 | sort -n; } | sed 's/$/p/')" file
```

The command substitution prints out a sed program to print 500 random lines from the file, but they are in order:

- `echo 1` => the header is always included
- `seq $(wc -l <file)` => print the numbers from 1 to the number of lines in the file
- `sed 1d` => delete the first line ("1") - don't want the header twice
- `shuf` => shuffle the line numbers
- `head -n 500` => take 500 of them
- `sort -n` => sort the numbers numerically
- `sed 's/$/p/'` => add a "p" to the end of each line

Then, the outer sed program does something like

```
sed -n "1p; 5p; 199p; 201p; ... 4352p" file
```

Comment: Elegant solution! But you need to change `500` to `499` to be 100% correct.

Comment: It's not crystal clear to me that the OP wants the header and then 499 or 500 lines.

Comment: If we're allowed to use lots pipes and lots of external tools and forks and fancy options and a little bit of Bashism we can get to: `sed -n -f <(shuf -i 2-"$(wc -l < file)" -n 500 | sed 's/$/p/') file`

Comment: @Ssank, I'm curious: was it my first answer or the second that was most helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
filename=file.txt
lines=500

head -1 $filename
tail -n+2 $filename | shuf | head -n $((lines-1))
```

**Explanation**.

This command prints header only:

```
head -1 $filename
```

This command prints everything but header:

```
tail -n+2 $filename
```

Since one line (header) was already printed, there is only `500-1` lines left to be printed:

```
head -n $((lines-1))
```

Also, as was mentioned, it's better to use `shuf` instead of `sort -r` to shuffle the lines, because `sort -r` gives you the same order of lines every time.

Comment: `sort -R`, on the other hand, does much the same as `shuf`; I guess that is what OP meant to write...

Comment: if I do  head -1 filename| tail -n+2 filename |shuf |head -n 499 > te, only the randomly selected rows get written in file te, not the header

Comment: @Ssank, you shouldn't. After first command (`head -1`) you will have only one line (header) and next you are passing **only** this header to next commands, missing rest of your file. Please note that there are **two** commands executing *sequentially* and *independently*: `head -1` prints header and then `tail -n+2` prints rest of file. You are trying to connect them to **one** pipeline, and you now have completely different behavior (which is wrong). To fix this, please replace first `|` in your command to `;`.